# PHP: Search in more tables at once?

Tags: php, sql

How do i make a mysql query for more tables to check at once?
i mean, something like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE username = '$username'");
$numer = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo "You have ".$number;
```

can you do like this?

What i want to do is to show a user all his posts from the whole site..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the query you provided, its using a full outer-join.
Use union selects instead.

```
SELECT username FROM table1 WHERE username = '$username'
UNION SELECT username FROM table2 WHERE username = '$username'
UNION SELECT username FROM table3 WHERE username = '$username'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with a `UNION`.

Change the Select-Statement in your mysql_query to...

```
SELECT username FROM table1 WHERE username = '$username'
UNION
SELECT username FROM table2 WHERE username = '$username'
UNION
SELECT username FROM table3 WHERE username = '$username'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL **[union keyword](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)** for that. It is used to union the tables and get the desired data out of them.