# PHP-reaching more data at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I make in PHP, that from my SQL baze are written all data, if value parent is not 0 from the same table, it find value from the line, which is the same idas parent.

I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350716/php-search-in-more-tables-at-once) but I want data from one table.

Similar as below written, but in one query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC;";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($rez = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $query="SELECT * FROM ".$dbPrefix."posts WHERE
    id=".$rez['parent']."";
    $parents = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($parent = $parents->fetch_assoc()) {
        $parentName=$parent['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the description of what you want.  I simply do not understand it.

Comment: I would like to do as I wrote in that code, but only in one query

Comment: Using a subquery would be an option `SELECT p.*, (SELECT pp.name FROM \`".$dbPrefix."posts\` as pp WHERE
    pp.id=p.parent) as parentname FROM \`posts\` as p ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: Thank you. That's what I searched